# Fetch records from two tables in sql server

Tags: sql

I have two table in sql server like this .

**table 1**

```
userid    value
a          1  
b          1
c          1
d          1
```

**table 2**

```
userid         value
e                0
f                0
g                0
a                0
b                0
```

I want to output like this from above two tables

```
usrid           value
a                0
b                0 
c                1
d                1
e                0
f                0 
g                0
```

if any records exists in table 1, records must fetches the data from table 2, other wise table 1. if userid not exists in table 1 and fetches records from table 2 only.

Comment: IF any userid matched, then the value fetched from the table 2..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  table1.userid NOT IN (select userid from table2)

UNION

SELECT *
FROM   table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  ISNULL(t1.usrid,t2.usrid) as usrid
       ,ISNULL(t1.value,t2.value) as value
from table1 t1
outer join table2 t2 on t1.usrid = t2.usrid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_2 AS t WHERE t.uid  IN (SELECT t2.uid FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t2)
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t WHERE t.uid NOT IN (SELECT t2.uid FROM dbo.Table_2 AS t2)
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_2 AS t WHERE t.uid NOT IN (SELECT t2.uid FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  userid NOT IN (select userid from table2)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   table2
```